# probability involving conditional prob

Tags: probability, statistics, bayes-theorem

I just want to know if i am able to prove that
$P(A|B,C)P(B|C)=P(A|C)$

I tried to solve but i couldn't get rid of the B,C intersection part.
I cancelled a lot of terms but the $P(B,C|A)$ term is bothering me.
thanks!

Comment: You can show the left-hand side is $\Pr((A\cap B)\mid C)$.

Comment: yeah i ended up with that and right side is P(A|C) but does that mean both sides are not equal?

Comment: No, it does not mean that.  However, it gives a hint on how to construct a counterexample. For instance, suppose that $\Pr(C)=1$. Then $\Pr(X\mid C)=\Pr(X)$. So to construct a counterexample all we need is to make $\Pr(C)=1$ and $\Pr(A\cap B)\ne \Pr(A)$.

Answer (score 2):

Your statement is not true, so you cannot prove it! On the other hand what would be true is a statement of the following form: (Where I am assuming that by $A$, $B$, $C$ you are denoting events).

$$P(A|C)= P(A|B,C)P(B|C) +  P(A|\neg B,C)P(\neg B|C) $$

By $\neg B$ I am denoting the complementary event of $B$, i.e. if $\Omega$ is your sample space, then $\neg B = \Omega \setminus B$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\Pr(X\mid Y)=\frac{\Pr(X\cap Y)}{\Pr(Y)}$.

Using that a couple of times, we get that the left-hand side is equal to $\Pr((A\cap B)\mid C)$.

Now we have a clue for producing an example where this not $\Pr(A\mid C)$.

Let $C$ be any event with probability $1$. Toss a fair coin once. Let $A$ be the event we get a head, and let $B$ be the event we get a tail. Then $\Pr(A\mid B,C)=0$ so the product on the left-hand side is $0$, while $\Pr(A|C)=1/2$.  (One can also construct less trivial counterexamples!)

Comment: i know what you mean but here comes the actual problem I was trying to solve by applying actual concepts, I used common sense to solve it and it works but here is the problem

An insurance company insures red and green cars.
number insured for red and green, 300 and 700
prob an accident occurs, 0.1 and 0.05
prob that the claim exceeds the deductible, given an accident occurs from this group 0.9 and 0.80
Find the prob the claim is on the red given claims exceed the deductible
My looking simple law of total probability and bayes theorem would work but I am trying to relate everything together

Comment: That is a conditional probability problem of more or less the usual type. The left-hand side of your conjectured equality is relevant, though not necessary.

Comment: yeah but the equality wouldn't work i guess should just use common sense to solve such problem...instead of making stuff more complicated that it should?

Comment: Common sense is fine, though mistakes of reasoning about conditional probability are common. I would set up the thing fairly formally, then use $\Pr(X\mid Y)=\frac{\Pr(X\cap Y)}{\Pr(Y)}$, and then use common sense to calculate the probabilities on the right.